# Use XNIO or Netty for writing a client side (JDBC driver) application?

Tags: java, jdbc, network-programming, netty

Assume the following scenario:
I want to write (or rewrite) a JDBC driver (client side) using NIO, using pure NIO seems to be overly complex, and two of the recommended choices are Netty and XNIO, there are others like Apache MINA that can be considered too.

So the question is, for a client side application, which fits best for this based on:

- Easy of use to implement a codec (protocol) on it.
- Allow easy shaded jar (don't have awful dependency spaghetti)
- First-class TLS support.
- Have good documentation.
- Don't break things often.

Or is using just plain *java.net* more easy, efficient and enought for this job?

Comment: Why? The rate-determining step is the database, not the network API. Save your time and use `java.net`.

Comment: So you think that is worthless to use NIO? Is gaining the thread-conservative and throughput benefits of non-blocking I/O not a good option for this usecase?

Comment: What threads? This isn't a server: it's a client. And what 'throughput benefits of non-blocking I/O'? Where did you read that?

Comment: Quote from XNIO: XNIO provides a unique API for combining blocking and non-blocking operations, even on the same channel, allowing you to take advantage of the simplicity and low latency of blocking I/O while still gaining the thread-conservative and throughput benefits of non-blocking I/O.

Comment: Well (a) as you are running in threads allocated by the client, there is no opportunity to conserve threads, and (b) the claim about 'throughput benefits of non-blocking I/O' is baseless. The rate-limiting step is the network, not whether the API you're using is blocking, non-blocking, or asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is using just plain java.net more easy, efficient and enought for this job?

Yes. The overheads are in the network and at the server. The benefits of NIO in a client are minimal. Specifically, you don't get to conserve threads, because you're not a server, and the 'throughput benefits of non-blocking I/O' you allege in comments are non-existent.

Comment: You are probably right EJP, do you have a post, reference or benchmark that shows that the benefits of NIO in a client are minimal? How about implementing an async api?

Comment: I have posted these statements about NIO in clients many times here. Regarding async, same answer: no throughput benefit is possible, and you risk using *more* threads. You'll have enough of a job on your hands implementing it with `java.net`, trust me.